# Cannot setup Jupyterhub+Jupyterlab to run as a service on Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, service, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub, systemctl

I am supposed to set up Jupyterhub Server for my team at work The idea is that everybody gets a JupyterLab interface in the browser when they access  `http://ourserverip:<port>`. I've been following this [link](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.0/installation-guide-hard.html) for the instructions. I literally followed every step at the exact same order and fail at starting `jupyterhub.service`.

I deviated from the link in terms of `[Environment]` and `ExecStart` in my `jupyterhub.service` file. They propose

```
Environment="PATH=/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/jupyterhub/bin"
ExecStart=/opt/jupyterhub/bin/jupyterhub -f /opt/jupyterhub/etc/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py
```

which couldn't find my jupyterhub binary (cannot reproduct `systemctl status jupyterhub.service` at this step but it the problem was finding jupyterhub binary), so I changed it to `/usr/local/bin` in the following way.

```
Environment="PATH=/usr/local/bin"
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/jupyterhub --ip=0.0.0.0  --port=8999  -f /usr/local/bin/jupyterhub_config.py
```

Now it finds the binary but fails at starting a proxy.The output of my `sudo systemctl status jupyterhub.service` is the following:

```
● jupyterhub.service - JupyterHub
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/jupyterhub.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-08-19 13:31:18 CEST; 5min ago
    Process: 9583 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/jupyterhub --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8999 -f /usr/local/bin/jupyterhub_config.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 9583 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

авг 19 13:31:18 companyname jupyterhub[9583]:       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jupyterhub/app.py", line 3048, in start
авг 19 13:31:18 companyname jupyterhub[9583]:         await self.proxy.start()
авг 19 13:31:18 companyname jupyterhub[9583]:       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jupyterhub/proxy.py", line 719, in start
авг 19 13:31:18 companyname jupyterhub[9583]:         _check_process()
авг 19 13:31:18 companyname jupyterhub[9583]:       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jupyterhub/proxy.py", line 715, in _check_process
авг 19 13:31:18 companyname jupyterhub[9583]:         raise e from None
авг 19 13:31:18 companyname jupyterhub[9583]:     RuntimeError: Proxy failed to start with exit code 127
авг 19 13:31:18 companyname jupyterhub[9583]:     
авг 19 13:31:18 companyname systemd[1]: jupyterhub.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
авг 19 13:31:18 companyname systemd[1]: jupyterhub.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I tried reinstalling configurable-http-proxy, updating nodejs version, as well as experimenting with different configurations for binary paths in jupyterhub.service. Depending on a combination it either cannot find a file, or cannot start a proxy.

I'm stuck on this for days, so if anyone has a idea on how to approach this please advise.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem.

The reason for this error is all about the environment. Systemd runs the service in a different environment than when you run jupyterhub in the login shell.

**Your login shell will load `/etc/environment`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc` and others, but systemd loads NONE OF THOSE.**

So you have to load the proper environment yourself, and it's not enough to just specify environment `path=/usr/local/bin`, especially jupyterhub needs to be run with node>=18, which added its own path and load nvm in `.bashrc`.

A better way to create systemd service will be using a shell script like this,

create a jupyterhub-service.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# tell shell the HOME path
export HOME="/root"

# copy the jupyterhub related codes from your existing ~/.bashrc,
# node/nvm env setting for example.
# it is not recommended to use source ~/.bashrc directly, as it may 
# execute other code that is not relevant to jupyterhub service, 
# or .bashrc may be inappropriately altered later.

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

exec /usr/local/bin/jupyterhub -f /your/config/path/jupyterhub_config.py
```

and `chmod u+x jupyterhub-service.sh` to make it executable

and then in `/etc/systemd/system/jupyterhub.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=JupyterHub
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root

# add environment variables for jupyterhub config here
Environment="OAUTH_CLIENT_ID=xxxxxx"
Environment="OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET=xxxxxxxxx"
Environment="PATH=/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"

# now you can exec your service
ExecStart=/your/.sh/path/jupyterhub-service.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

time to get things on the right track

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable jupyterhub.service
sudo systemctl start jupyterhub.service
```

Enjoy!